# How to avoid Scrollbar stretch in Android List view

Tags: android

I tried to used `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"` parameter to add image as scrollbar. The scroll bar was changed but the problem is, it won't show the original size, it was streted depending on listview size (items). If the List item count is 20 means it show right dimension, it goes around 50 means, the scroll bar is stretched in entire view. Is there a way to avoid stretching. Here i will add my code with scroll bar image as well as my out put too.

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#234232"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbarSize="12dip"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomScrollBarAndroidActivity.java**

```
public class CustomScrollBarAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView list;
    private static List<String> listItems = initListItems();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
    }


    private static List<String> initListItems() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean isNotFinish = true;
        int i = 0;
        while(isNotFinish){
            list.add("list item #" + i);
            if (i > 50){
                isNotFinish = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

[image: My output image is],

my Scroll bar image is [image]

Comment: Why not use a nine patch image with the stretch area in the middle of the image?

Comment: @Luksprog: Sorry i doesn't know how to use nine patch image for that. Could you plz guide me

Answer (score 2):

Use draw9 patch for this image :)

Comment: this link will help you (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: I tired with this tutorial, black line was drawn around the image, but nothing will happen in scroll bar. It still same..

Comment: This is the only way to avoid this. but you have to correctly understand this tutorial because drawing line at wrong place will not solve the problem.

Comment: I can't do any thing more than this as i am using this tool for about 2 years for this kind of problems.